# Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput and tap to correct bar?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

With XNA and Windows Phone, using Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput doesn't seem to use the native "tap to correct words" bar.

Is there any way to get it to show up, or is it a current XNA 4.0 limitation on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/which_product_for_windows_phone) article:

*If your application requires keyboard support, then you should consider Silverlight. Silverlight applications get access to the software keyboard by default, but for games made with XNA Game Studio, developers need to build their own software keyboard control to enable keyboard input.*

With XNA, you can only use Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput, and this doesn't have the functionality you desire.

Comment: Or, as described in that same article, you could use XNA from within a Silverlight app.